# Edit the colspan attribute of specific rows in a table with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an HTML table in my page. like this

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
    <thead>
    <tr class="tablewhite">
        <th>&nbsp;No</th>
        <th>Options</th>
        <th>Dash</th>
        <th>mm</th>
        <th>Inch</th>
        <th>mm</th>
        <th>mm</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="tablecontentwhite">
        <td>19904408</td>
        <td>S/G</td>
        <td>-4</td>
        <td>4.4</td>
        <td>5/16"</td>
        <td>7.9</td>
        <td>20.0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tablecontentblue">
        <td>&nbsp;Material: Acidproof Stainless Steel with bronze inserted thread.</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tablecontentwhite">
        <td>&nbsp;-  K=Clevis Pin Treaded w/Nut, G=Clevis Pin w/G-ring</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

There is a chance that last three rows of the table may differ in structure. Like I show above, last two rows have text in only first column. If only first column of the column have text in it, I want to give it maximum width. In this case add `colspan="7"` to the column with text and remove all empty columns in that row. Desired output will be like this

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr class="tablewhite">
      <th>&nbsp;No</th>
      <th>Options</th>
      <th>Dash</th>
      <th>mm</th>
      <th>Inch</th>
      <th>mm</th>
      <th>mm</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="tablecontentwhite">
      <td>19904408</td>
      <td>S/G</td>
      <td>-4</td>
      <td>4.4</td>
      <td>5/16"</td>
      <td>7.9</td>
      <td>20.0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tablecontentblue">
      <td colspan="7">&nbsp;Material: Acidproof Stainless Steel with bronze inserted thread.</td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="tablecontentwhite">
      <td colspan="7">&nbsp;- K=Clevis Pin Treaded w/Nut, G=Clevis Pin w/G-ring</td>

    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Can any one point out the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: check the sub cells are empty if empty delete them and increase previous cell colspan

Comment: @raghavendra can you add it as an answer with necessary code sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just giving an idea. you can try this. works with next empty elements.

```
    $('tr').each(function(index, tr) {
    var previous = false;
    $(tr).find('td').each(function(index1, td) {
        if(td.innerText == "") {
            if(previous) {
                var p = $(previous);
                if(!p.attr('colspan')) {
                    p.attr('colspan', 1);
                }
                p.attr('colspan', parseInt(p.attr('colspan'))+1);
                $(td).remove();
            }
        } else {
            previous = td;
        }
    });
});
```

you can also simply write like this

```
 $('tr').each(function(index, tr) {
    $(this).find('td:not(:empty)').attr('colspan', $(this).find('td:empty').length);
    $(this).find('td:empty').remove();
});
```

for splitting cells length you can change the second line

```
$(this).find('td:not(:empty)').attr('colspan', $(this).find('td:empty').length/$(this).find('td:not(:empty)'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lmtx2ncq/

Comment: in the example it checks with next cell only. Can you please explain how I could make it like. "check all cells except first are empty".

Comment: @Athul which solution you are using 1st or 2nd?

Comment: @Athul you can use slice to it

Comment: "slice to it" , I don't get it.

Comment: $(this).find('td:empty').slice(1) will skips the first td in a tr so that use like that